# Check if a realmObject has been updated

Tags: android, realm

The [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmObject.html) for `realmObject.isValid()` says:

> `isValid()` Checks if the `realmObject` is still valid to use i.e., the
>   `realmObject` hasn't been deleted nor has the `Realm` been closed.

But, what would `isValid()` return for a `realmObject` which has been updated in another thread?

Will `Realm` update the `realmObject` held in the current thread (non updating thread) or just consider it as `invalid`?

The documentation seems to not provide an answer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Multithreading

> Will realm update the realmObject held in the current thread (non updating thread)?

Answer is **YES**, if auto-update is enabled on the given thread, which requires a Looper. This is described at [Threading](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#threading) section:

> There’s actually very little you need to know, or do, when working with various threads with Realm. The key takeaway here is that Realm makes it effortless to work with data on multiple threads without having to worry about consistency or performance because objects and queries are auto-updating at all times.

### Updating state

> But, what would isValid() return for a realmObject which has been updated in another thread?

You can to add update listener which will notify your UI components (for example) if data will updated. This is described at [Notification](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications) section.

Comment: `because objects and queries are auto-updating at all times.` only if auto-update is enabled on the given thread, which requires a Looper

Comment: not understand example with list ? i have a realmlist is null because was delete but now have.. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal State: Object is no longer valid to operate on. Was it deleted by another thread?`

Comment: @marlonpya, please, create new question with shared code. And I will try to help you

Comment: Hi men. No problem yesterday I solved my problem by adding `RealmChangeListener`.